# Unable to minify my static files in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, minify

I’m using Maven 3.3.  I want to minify my the JS and CSS files in my WAR projects, so I put the following in my parent pom …

```
<profile>
    <id>minifi-static-files</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-minify</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <cssSourceDir>css</cssSourceDir>
                            <jsSourceDir>js</jsSourceDir>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>minify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

However, after I run

```
mvn clean install
```

at the root level where the parent pom is located, none of the JS or CSS files is minified (they appear the same as before).  Should I be doing something different in my configuration above?

**Edit** Below is debugging from including "-X"

```
[INFO] --- minify-maven-plugin:1.7.4:minify (default-minify) @ myproject ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=10, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=10, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=10, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=14, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=0}
[DEBUG] com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:jar:1.7.4:
[DEBUG]    com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.7:compile
[DEBUG]       rhino:js:jar:1.6R7:compile
[DEBUG]    com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:v20140814:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-externs:jar:v20140814:compile
[DEBUG]       args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.26:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:runtime
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:1.7.4
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:1.7.4
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < project>org.mainco.subco:myproject:90.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:1.7.4
[DEBUG]   Included: com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:jar:1.7.4
[DEBUG]   Included: com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.7
[DEBUG]   Included: rhino:js:jar:1.6R7
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:v20140814
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-externs:jar:v20140814
[DEBUG]   Included: args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.26
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.json:json:jar:20090211
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:1.7.4:minify from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:1.7.4, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@33909752]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:1.7.4:minify' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) bufferSize = 4096
[DEBUG]   (f) charset = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) closureAngularPass = false
[DEBUG]   (f) closureCompilationLevel = SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
[DEBUG]   (f) closureCreateSourceMap = false
[DEBUG]   (f) closureExterns = []
[DEBUG]   (f) closureLanguage = ECMASCRIPT3
[DEBUG]   (f) closureSortDependencies = false
[DEBUG]   (f) closureUseDefaultExterns = false
[DEBUG]   (f) cssEngine = YUI
[DEBUG]   (f) cssFinalFile = style.css
[DEBUG]   (f) cssSourceDir = css
[DEBUG]   (f) cssSourceExcludes = []
[DEBUG]   (f) cssSourceFiles = []
[DEBUG]   (f) cssSourceIncludes = []
[DEBUG]   (f) jsEngine = YUI
[DEBUG]   (f) jsFinalFile = script.js
[DEBUG]   (f) jsSourceDir = js
[DEBUG]   (f) jsSourceExcludes = []
[DEBUG]   (f) jsSourceFiles = []
[DEBUG]   (f) jsSourceIncludes = []
[DEBUG]   (f) nosuffix = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMerge = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMinify = false
[DEBUG]   (f) suffix = min
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) webappSourceDir = /Users/davea/Documents/sb_workspace/myproject/src/main/webapp
[DEBUG]   (f) webappTargetDir = /Users/davea/Documents/sb_workspace/myproject/target/myproject
[DEBUG]   (f) yuiDisableOptimizations = false
[DEBUG]   (f) yuiLineBreak = -1
[DEBUG]   (f) yuiNoMunge = false
[DEBUG]   (f) yuiPreserveSemicolons = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Starting CSS task:
[INFO] Starting JavaScript task:
```

Comment: Interestingly, when I run "mvn help:active-profiles," my profile containing this plugin isn't showing up.  Does Maven have some kind of restriction against declaring multiple profiles activeByDefault?

Comment: The debug log is when I frocbily told it to run th eprofile by including "-P profileName".  To your other comment, I used to have that but samaxes below told me to use cssSourceDir instead so I switched them out.

Comment: If someone have same problem using maven 3.6+ then please downgrade to 3.5.4 and the problem will be sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default minify-maven-plugin looks for CSS files inside `${basedir}/src/main/webapp/css` folder and JavaScript files inside `${basedir}/src/main/webapp/js` folder.

Have a look at `webappSourceDir`, `cssSourceDir` and `jsSourceDir` options in the plugin goal overview page: http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/minify-mojo.html.

Comment: Hi @Dave, I'm saying that if your CSS and JS files are not located in the default locations you need to configure the options I enumerated above.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question to include the debug logs and change the config to use "jsSourdeDir" and "cssSourceDir" insetad of what I had, per your suggestion.  However, nothing is getting minified.  Per the docs, the jsSourceDir and cssSourceDir are relative to src/main/webapp, so is there something wrong with the phase I'm using?

Comment: What is the full path to your CSS and JS directories?

Comment: The paths are "/my_workspace/project/src/main/webapp/js/" and "/my_workspace/project/src/main/webapp/css/".

Comment: Please try the following configuration:

<configuration>  
    <cssSourceIncludes>
      <cssSourceInclude>**</cssSourceInclude>
    </cssSourceIncludes>
    <jsSourceIncludes>
        <jsSourceInclude>**</jsSourceInclude>
    </jsSourceIncludes>
</configuration>

Comment: K, that definitely produced a whirlwind of activity.  Now I'm getting errors like "[ERROR] syntax error at script.js line 10553:1, }); //end define", but that may not have anything to do witih your configuration, so let me try and research those more to figure out what is happening before I come back and accept.